# Что представляет restrictions generic в java?

Tags: java

Собственно, не могу понять, для чего нужны ограничения generic, толком инфы про это не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type Safety, есть такое понятие. Вы, например, объявляет коллекцию строк как `Collection<String>`. Ну и на этапе компиляции вы не сможете запихнуть туда что-то другое.

Answer (score 2):

Инфы полно: раз (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html ) и два (http://www.quizful.net/post/java-generics-tutorial ). Это сходу, а сколько еще всего понаписано.